# Appropriate way to replace a string?

Tags: c#, regex

my input is `abc@xyz.com`

I want to replace `xyz.com` with `mnop.com`

So the final result will be `abc@mnop.com`

The present way

```
var input = "abc@xyz.com";
var output = input.Split('@')[0] + "@mnop.com";
```

What is the appropriate way?Any regular expression?

Comment: I think this is fine.

Comment: If you want to replace X with Y, why not `input.Replace(X, Y);`? There is no need for regexps or splits

Comment: Yes, it's fine, regulars are expensive for this task.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen because perhaps the domain isn't known at compile time. What you have here is as good as any other solution.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - i dont thik that he gets alwaays the same X... (not always xyz.com)

Comment: @James, @Cadburry The question only refers to `xyz.com`, not "any domain name" or other things.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the OPs solution suggests they aren't interested in what the current domain is which also suggests they most likely don't know what it is, they just want to replace it.

Comment: @James Then they can adjust it based on when they know it. There can be a variable, I don't think that needs to be spoonfed to them. If it would more complicated than a single domain name, it would be mentioned.

Comment: @James I don't accept that. Since both the original string and the replacement string uses placeholder domain names we have nothing to suggest these are entirely random in either space. Some of the answers below answer *perfectly* the question above, why they were downvoted is unknown to me but if this question is about something else, it should be *rewritten with the correct question*.

Comment: This might be better off on **Code Review**.

Comment: In other words, if some of the answers below *doesn't answer the question*, then the question is unclear and should be closed as such.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I disagree, part of what I love about SO is answers incorporate the bigger picture, some of the best answers on here don't answer the question directly but rather suggest alternatives and explain the reasoning why. The point is, data changes and even if it is a single email in this case, a solution that will adapt regardless of the input is a *better* solution that one that hardcodes data.

Comment: I agree to that but it may also be that the OP simply doesn't know that there is a `string.Replace` method available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace function sample (with correct exception handle)

```
/// <summary>
/// replace email domain
/// </summary>
/// <param name="email"> email </param>
/// <param name="newDomain"> new domain </param>
/// <returns></returns>
private string ReplaceMailDomain(string email, string newDomain)
{
    if (email == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("email");

    int pos = email.IndexOf('@');
    if (pos < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid email", "email");
    }
    else
    {
        return email.Substring(0, pos + 1) + newDomain;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string email = ReplaceMailDomain("abc@xyz.com", "mnop.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know before hand the string you are looking for, you can simply use the normal `Replace(string toFind, string replacement)`. You can use `indexof` and `substring` to get the domain name.

Given the below:

```
        string input = "abc@xyz.com";
        string domain = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('@') + 1);
        Console.WriteLine(input.Replace(domain, "mnop.com"));
```

It yields

```
abc@mnop.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "take something before `@` sign and append some domain name", then one of possible approaches is

```
var input = "abc@xyz.com";
var output = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('@')) + "@mnop.com";
```

It is slightly "lightweight" than using `Split` because it doesn't creates array (and in fact you doesn't need array since you're using only its first element).

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the address will be valid, meaning there is only one @ character, you can use the simple `Replace()` function

```
var domain = "xyz.com";
var newdomain = "xyz.com";

var input = "abc@xyz.com";
var output = input.Replace("@" + domain, "@" + newdomain);
```

Regexps would be overkill for this.

If you want to remove *any* domain name and replace it, then use `Substring()` and `IndexOf()` for that

```
var output = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf('@') + 1) + newdomain;
```

Note that this will throw an exception if the string doesn't contain the @ character.

Comment: And if xyz.com isn't known at compile time? Also, "*splits are overkill for this*", seriously?

Comment: I really don't appreciate downvoting based on "the OP *might* have wanted something different" without them explicitly saying that.